# Is there any way to write dynamic queries in Postgres' SQL dialect without using PL/pgSQL?

Tags: postgresql, dynamic-sql

I need to write dynamic query in Postgres which should not be a function/procedure.

I tried using Prepare and execute statement but, could not find any thing wherein i would generate a plain text and then execute.

```
SET @sql = 'SELECT @endDate = endDate from '+@metadbname+'.dbo.sometable where some condition';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, some_variables
```

Can we have any variation of above query in PostgreSQL without using PL/pgSQL.

Comment: No, that's not possible. Dynamic SQL can only be used in PL/pgSQL

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name whenever i need to write dynamic query i should write it in a function i.e pl/pgsql? Is that a compulsion?

Comment: Yes, SQL can't run dynamic SQL. You need some kind of programming language. But why do you need to pass table names to functions? This might indicate a problem with your data model.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I was just studying whether we can do it in SQL. Because same thing can be achieved in MS SQL Server. Thanks, for your answers!

Comment: Postgres (like essentially all other DBMS except SQL Server) makes a clear distinction between the query language (SQL) and the procedural language (PL/pgSQL). SQL does not define any control structure or variables - including dynamic SQL.  That's is only available in procedural code. While SQL Server's approach is sometimes quite convenient, it's a very uncommon implementation.

Comment: Fair question. When I need really complex dynamic code, I build it in the application layer using procedural code. I did this last month for an interactive pivot table UI and it went well. With that said, writing injection-safe code in PL/pgSQL for normal tasks is a good default strategy in Postgres.